# java config for SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor in an MDB

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, config

I am trying to expose an MDB interface for an existing jaxws service. The jaxws implementation is wired using Spring's java configuration and I would like to reuse that for the MDB as well, injecting a delegate into the MDB that will be called from onMessage().

I am trying to use the SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor as per the documentation.
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/ejb.html#ejb-implementation-ejb3

But the documentation referes only to the XML configuration. There is a mention of an option to override the getBeanFactory() but no details are given.

Is there a way to use Spring's java configuration (@Configuration) with the SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up packaging the the MDB inside the WAR along with the web service as documented at http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/cejb_ejbinwar.html.